# How do I shuffle the print statement of 3 separate functions?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def a():
  print(a)
def b():
  print(b)
def c():
  print(c)
```

How do I shuffle a, b and c? I cannot print a,b,c out of the function because there is additional code that I haven't mentioned here in order to simplify the question. I've tried putting all 3 inside random.shuffle() and also tried to associate variables with each function and tried to shuffle the variables (this also doesn't work out because of the code inside each function).

Send help.

Comment: The number of ways to do this is indefinite. For one, you could shuffle _the functions themselves_, and only call them in the order given in the post-shuffle list.

Comment: Do you want to call these functions in a random order? Please show the expected output.

Comment: That is to say: `funcs_to_call = [a, b, c]`, then `random.shuffle(funcs_to_call)`, then `for f in funcs_to_call: f()`

Comment: @CharlesDuffy sorry didn't see this while I was making my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you are most likely running into is that you calling the functions inside of your shuffle. Just put the functions themselves without calling them and you can easily do this:

```
random.shuffle([a,b,c]) # correct
# vs.
random.shuffle([a(),b(),c()]) # incorrect, calls functions before shuffle
```

Then you can do a for loop and call them or whatever you need:

```
for f in random.shuffle([a,b,c]):
  f()
```